# How to change the value in another column of a certain category in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on a dataframe and in a certain column I have different categories of classes (organism taxonomy). In this class column there are 105 unique classes in the +/- 3000 rows. You can view each row as a species. Multiple species can belong to 1 class.

For the class "Unknown" in this class column, I would like to change the value of the column "Superkingdom_name" in each of the rows which have "Unknown" in the class column. How is this done?

I'm currently clueless of how to do this.

So I expect to change the value of "Superkingdom_name" for every row that has value "unknown" in the class column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the very limited information you have provided, I think you can use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method. Assuming your data is stored in a `df`:

```
df.loc[df['class'] == "Unknown", 'Superkingdom_name'] = "new_value"
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thank you SO much for the quick and effective reply.